# Big-Oh, Big-Omega, Big-Theta

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics

Can someone provide concrete reasoning for how to solve the following equations with respect to Big-Oh, Big-Omega, and Big-Theta?

\begin{equation} 6n^2 + 20n = O(n^3) \end{equation}
\begin{equation} 6n^2 + 20n = Ω(n^3) \end{equation}
\begin{equation} 6n^2 + 20n = Θ(n^3) \end{equation}

My teacher began discussing these concepts but I was confused when he explained it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did he give definitions? If not, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: Intuitively, $f = O(g)$ means $f \leq g$, $f = \Omega(g)$ means $f \geq g$, and $f = \Theta(g)$ means $f \cong g$ (in the limit of large $n$, up to constant factors).

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, it's all about how fast the function grows. Big-O says upper limit-- $f(n)$ doesn't grow any faster(/slower) than $g(n)$ when $f(n)=O(n)$ (/$\Omega(n)$).

Your 2nd & 3rd equations are wrong. 1st is more accurate with small o.